# How to qualify for heat endurance with a lvl 3 wizard

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

How to qualify for heat endurance with a lvl 3 wizard is what im wondering.
We have 1 feat level one and 3 feats level 3

Comment: Is it accurate to assume the wizard must belong to race with a LA +0 or higher? (That is, must the Wiz3 be ECL 3?)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the race Orc (desert) gains *Endurance* as a racial bonus feat, which could be swapped out for Heat Endurance, per the fluff text, with DM approval. For the Sandstorm version, which is actually a half-orc that explicitly gains *Heat Endurance*, see [Scab-Orcs](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20050304a&page=3).

There is also a Touchstone site in Sandstorm, the Salt Sanctuary that grants *Improved Heat Endurance*, but obviously requires the *Touchstone* or *Planar Touchstone* feats.

I also believe that there is an option for Rangers to gain it as well, though this would not be so useful for a wizard.

Comment: *All* the Unearthed Arcana [desert races](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/races/environmentalRacialVariants.htm#desertRaces) gain heat endurance, though it's a Trait that is not identical to the Feat.

Comment: Quite so. Some DMs might allow the trait to function as the feat for qualification purposes, so that is worth mentioning. Also, the specifically mentioned Orc explicitly gains Endurance, which again, a flexible DM might allow to be swapped out due to fluff text, as mentioned.

Comment: You're right... so they get heat endurance trait, *and* endurance feat.